# How can I prove that the log-likelihood function for logistic regression is globally concave?

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, optimization

For my master thesis, I have to show/prove that the log-likelihood function for logistic regression is globally concave. My supervisor told me that one way to show this is to use the fact that $X'X$ is positive definite and using this I can show that the Hessian of the log-likelihood is negative definite. I managed to show that if $X$ is of full rank then $X'X$ is positive definite. However, I don't know how to proceed from here and would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Hint: logsumexp https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/def_lse_fcn.html is your friend.  You may also benefit from understanding which function composition operations preserve convexity (or concavity), as expounded in section 3.2 of http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf .

Comment: @ Mark L. Stone. Thank you very much for the links! (It's definitely not all I have to do, that would be ridiculous)