# What is global concavity of the (log-)likelihood worth in Bayesian estimation?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, bayesian-optimization, log-concave

In maximum likelihood estimation there is a big emphasis on finding the *global* maximum, which is why likelihood functions that are provably globally (log-)concave are desirable (despite often being overly simple, like the Gaussian, [logistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/191020), Tobit, etc).

Bayesian estimation, of course, is for the most part integration rather than optimization (INLA and others aside). But I wondered if a simple but provably concave (or log-concave) likelihood "buys" something extra in the Bayesian setting, say more leeway in the choice of (improper) priors?

Comment: Maybe depends for example in the sampler... there are some methods called _Gradient-based MCMC_ which for sure if you feed some convex log-likelihood ensures that you  are going to have a nice distribution (where a non concave may leads to samples always near the local minima, aka suffers of the same problems as usual optimization)

Comment: That's more of a computational benefit. I was thinking of something benefits the model building process. For instance (and this is just a guess), it could be that if a likelihood function probably doesn't have ridges or flat portions, a wider range of priors still leads to a proper posterior.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $\theta$ is our parameter(s) of interest and $D$ is the data, Bayes theorem gives us $P(\theta|D)\propto P(\theta)\cdot P(D|\theta)$ where $P(\theta)P(D|\theta)$ is the prior and $P(D|\theta)$ is the likelihood.

Now the optimal Bayesian estimator for $\theta$ (in terms of BMSE) is $E[\theta|D]$.  That is, in order to find the Bayesian estimator we derivate the posterior probability (or its log). While taking a concave prior (such as the normal) usually guarantees unimodality and getting the global extremum point, sometimes our prior isn't concave. In such cases, the optimality of the Bayes estimator indeed relies on the concavity of the the likelihood function.

For example, consider the [IRT 3PL model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory#Three_parameter_logistic_model) of answering correctly a binary-scored question: The question has parameters $a,b,c$ and given examinee ability $\theta$ the said probability is

$$P(y=1|a,b,c,\theta)=c+(1-c)\frac{\exp(a(\theta-b))}{1+\exp(a(\theta-b))}$$

In a similar manner the probability of the same examinee to answer the same question incorrectly is

$$Q=P(y=0|a,b,c,\theta)=1-P(y=1|a,b,c,\theta)=\frac{1-c}{1+\exp(a(\theta-b))}$$

Given the responses $D_j=\{y_{1j},...,y_{nj}\}$ of the $j^{th}$ examinee to $n$ questions, the likelihood function is

$$P(D_j|\theta_j)=\prod_{i=1}^n P_i^{y_{ij}}Q_i^{(1-y_{ij})}$$

Let $e_{ij}=\exp(a_i(\theta_j-b_i))$, the log-likelihood is $$\sum_i\left(y_{ij}\log(c_i+e_{ij})+(1-y_{ij})\log(1-c_i)-\log(1+e_{ij})\right)$$

The concavity of this function ensures the optimality of the Bayes estimator whether the prior $P(\theta)$ for modelling examinee ability is concave (e.g. normal) or not (which happens sometimes, especially in heterogenous populations where the empirical prior is multimodal). In other cases, if the likelihood isn't concave, we might force a concave prior to ensure Bayes optimality.